# Bokeh library: W-1001 (NO_DATA_RENDERERS): Plot has no data renderers:

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to do an interactive with widgets using bokeh library however I keep getting this error

```
W-1001 (NO_DATA_RENDERERS): Plot has no data renderers: Figure(id='41f32f65-22f9-4ff7-b4ea-54f83ec17b1f', ...)
```

what I'm trying to do is get an interactive plot with two widgets, where the value of one widget depends on the other, when I run the script I get the above error and an empty plot, however the widgets seem to be working fine, below is the python script I ran

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Select, HoverTool, Div
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot


def main():
    data = loc_ds[['Region', 'SubRegion', 'Date', 'change']]
    source = ColumnDataSource(data)

    p = figure(
        x_axis_label='Date',
        y_axis_label='Count',
        title='Data Plot'
    )

    hover = HoverTool()
    hover.tooltips = [
        ('Region', '@region'),
        ('Sub Region', '@sub_region'),
        ('Count', '@value')
    ]
    p.add_tools(hover)

    region_select = Select(title='Region', value='', options=list(data['Region'].unique()))
    sub_region_select = Select(title='Sub Region', value='', options=list(data['SubRegion'].unique()))

    def update_plot(attr, old, new):
        region = region_select.value
        sub_region = sub_region_select.value

        if region == '' or sub_region == '':
            p.title.text = 'Data Plot'
            p.x_range.start = undefined
            p.x_range.end = undefined
            p.renderers = []
        else:
            p.title.text = f'Data Plot for {region} - {sub_region}'
            p.x_range.start = source.data[source.data['Region'] == region]['Date'].min()
            p.x_range.end = source.data[source.data['Region'] == region]['Date'].max()
            p.line('Date', 'value', source=source[source.data['SubRegion'] == subregion], line_width=2)

    region_select.on_change('value', update_plot)
    sub_region_select.on_change('value', update_plot)


    layout = gridplot([[region_select, sub_region_select], [p]])
    show(layout)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What could be the issue here?

Comment: The "W" prefix indicates that this is a warning, not an error. It is a warning because in the vast majority of cases, generating a plot with no renderers is a mistake, and issuing a warning is an attempt to forestall "why is my plot blank" questions in that case. Bokeh provides an API to silence warnings if they do not apply to your case: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/validation.html

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce and understand your warning, please see the three lines below

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure()
show(p)
```

which also raises the warning

> WARNING:bokeh.core.validation.check:W-1000 (MISSING_RENDERERS): Plot has no renderers: figure(id='p1001', ...)

This warning tells you in other words, that there is no data to display and it will result in a blank plot.

To silence this warning and see something, add a renderer like `circle`. There are many different options for you. Please see the list in the [figure docs](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting/figure.html#figure) or follow the [first steps guide](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/first_steps.html).

The working minimal example below will create a figure with three circles and the warning will not appear.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

p = figure()
p.circle(x=[1,2,3], y=[1,2,3])
show(p)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to add dummy glyphs for this, Bokeh has an API to silence warnings: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/validation.html